# Self referencing objects and Breeze.js SaveChanges

Tags: entity-framework, breeze

I delete some childs of an deleted object to preserve foreign key conflicts by overriding `BeforeSaveEntity` in my derived EFContextProvider Class:

```
protected override bool BeforeSaveEntity(EntityInfo entityInfo)
{
    dbEntities db = new dbEntities();
    if (entityInfo.Entity.GetType() == typeof(ServerFile) && entityInfo.EntityState == EntityState.Deleted)
    {
         ServerFile filetodelete = entityInfo.Entity as ServerFile;
         if (filetodelete.OriginalFileID == null)
         {
             IEnumerable<ServerFile> f = db.ServerFiles.Where(x => x.OriginalFileID == filetodelete.ID);
             foreach (ServerFile fd in f)
                db.ServerFiles.Remove(fd);
         }
    }
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

In my derived ApiController class attributed with `[BreezeController]` I therefore refresh my context:

```
public SaveResult SaveChanges(JObject saveBundle)
{
    _contextProvider.ObjectContext.Refresh(RefreshMode.StoreWins, _contextProvider.ObjectContext.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted));
    return _contextProvider.SaveChanges(saveBundle);
}
```

But I still get the error:

```
An exception of type 'System.Exception' occurred in Breeze.ContextProvider.dll 
but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an
unexpected number of rows (0). Entities may have been modified or deleted since
entities were loaded. Refresh ObjectStateManager entries.
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have triggers on your database do you? I have seen that error being caused by triggers on the underlying table in the past.